# Meaning of "I am cold naked"

Tags: meaning

Does "I am cold naked" mean "I am cold because I am naked"?

Let's assume that Tom and Jane are talking.
When Tom says "I am cold naked" to Jane,
does Jane understand that Tom is cold because he is naked?

Otherwise, is it right to say "I am cold to be naked"?

Comment: This is a duplicate of deleted question #87368,  [Does “I am cold naked.” mean “ I am cold because I am naked”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87368), which like the above question has “Does Jane understand that Tome is cold because he is naked?” as part of it.  As a deleted question, 87368 is not eligible to be a duplicate of, which impedes voting to close this as a duplicate.  Oh well.

Comment: While it may be a duplicate, the question is now (I hope) clearly about the slightly unusual use of *cold*.

Comment: Pedantically, it would be "cold, naked". The comma being necessary to separate the two adjectives. Realistically, it would never be said (with apologies to MBRUGLIA NATALIE, "Im all out of faith, this is how I feel, Im cold and I am shamed lying naked on the floor"

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over without improving it. If you'd like to work on your older question, please flag it so you can edit.

Comment: @박용현: I feel that many of your questions would be better off in the beta version of this new site: [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=aXZD-aZLgRc8GxFV_g6lKw2). This is still in private beta, but you can choose to  follow it, so you will get notified when it is opened for public beta. When this happens, you can ask questions there in the same way you have done here, but in a site that is more suited for the questions you ask as a learner of english from a non-english perspective.

Answer (score 1):

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cold

> - *adverb*
>        *North American informal*
>           completely; entirely:
>        *we stopped cold behind a turn in the staircase*

It's really unusual to the point of non-existence in British English, but to use it in the sense of the OP's *completely naked* is comprehensible.

Comment: "North American informal" -- makes it a regionalism and non-mainstream, not-even-AmE in a broad sense. I would expect at least some native speakers of English in North America to be unfamiliar with it, let alone those from other parts of the world.

Comment: True, although of the definitions at that link, that one (alone) fits the usage.

Comment: I agree with this. In this context, I think "cold" is a synonym for "[buck](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buck+naked)".

Comment: I'm NA and while I know *stop cold* and *cold start* and *to coldstart*, I've never encountered *stone naked*. *Buck naked*, as @J.R. suggests, or *stark naked*, yes. I wonder if this isn't a variant (or a mishearing/misreporting) of **stone cold**; it's usually *stone cold dead*, but Google finds enough hits on *stone cold naked* to make this plausible.